# Is Facebook's Scribe maintained?

Tags: logging

I'm looking at tools to aggregate logs. I heard about Facebook's Scribe early last year at a conference. However, at this point the github account (https://github.com/facebook/scribe) has not been updated in a year? Is scribe still maintained? relevant? or should I just move on to other tools?